# Creating setup wizard on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, wizard

In my application I need to ask the user some information in the beginning. Like Google asks users when they first launch the phone.

Using Java and Android, how do I make the same kind of setup wizard for my application? I could create multiple activities and when moving to the next page in the wizard I'd launch that. That doesn't seem a good way to do it.

I'd like to use Eclipse's GUI builder to design it.

Comment: most of these implement some kind of viewpager as in this article : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 8):

Creating a wizard is explained here, also: https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/6cVymZvn3f4

You can get the code here:
https://github.com/romannurik/android-wizardpager

Comment: I think Roman Nurik example is too complex. There is a library that enables you to create wizard functionality very easy, check out [WizarDroid](http://wizardroid.codepond.org). It's well documented and on constant development.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is using Shared Preferences in android. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
You just need to check if the value is not already set then show your setup wizard else proceed straight to the application.

You can also show the wizard in dialog box or the other way is just develop a separate activity along with UI.